# Optimizing suggestions for a piece of Julia and Python code

Tags: python, performance, optimization, julia, numba

I have a program for a simulation and inside the program I have a function. I have realized that the function consumes most time of simulation. So, I am trying to optimize the funcion first. The function is as follows

Julia version 1.1:

```
function fun_jul(M,ksi,xi,x)

  F(n,x) = sin(n*pi*(x+1)/2)*cos(n*pi*(x+1)/2);
  K = length(ksi);
  Z = zeros(length(x),K);
  for n in 1:M
    for k in 1:K
        for l in 1:length(x)
          Z[l,k] +=  (1-(n/(M+1))^2)^xi*F(n,ksi[k])*F(n,x[l]);
        end
    end
  end

return Z

end
```

I also rewrite the above function in python+numba for comparison as follows

Python+numba

```
import numpy as np
from numba import prange, jit    
@jit(nopython=True, parallel=True)
def fun_py(M,ksi,xi,x):

    K = len(ksi);
    F = lambda nn,xx: np.sin(nn*np.pi*(xx+1)/2)*np.cos(nn*np.pi*(xx+1)/2);

    Z = np.zeros((len(x),K));
    for n in range(1,M+1):
        for k in prange(0,K):
            Z[:,k] += (1-(n/(M+1))**2)**xi*F(n,ksi[k])*F(n,x);


    return Z
```

But Julia codes are very slow here are my results:

Julia results:

```
using BenchmarkTools
N=400; a=-0.5; b=0.5; x=range(a,b,length=N); cc=x; M = 2*N+100; xi = M/40;
@benchmark fun_jul(M,cc,xi,x)

BenchmarkTools.Trial: 
  memory estimate:  1.22 MiB
  allocs estimate:  2
  --------------
  minimum time:     25.039 s (0.00% GC)
  median time:      25.039 s (0.00% GC)
  mean time:        25.039 s (0.00% GC)
  maximum time:     25.039 s (0.00% GC)
  --------------
  samples:          1
  evals/sample:     1
```

Python results:

```
N=400;a = -0.5;b = 0.5;x = np.linspace(a,b,N);cc = x;M = 2*N + 100;xi = M/40;

%timeit fun_py(M,cc,xi,x);
1.2 s ± 10.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Any help on improving the codes both for julia and python+numba would be appreciated.

**Updated**

Based on @Przemyslaw Szufel's answer and the other posts I have improved numba and julia codes. Now both are parallelized. Here are timings

*Python+Numba times:*

```
@jit(nopython=True, parallel=True)
def fun_py(M,ksi,xi,x):

    K = len(ksi);
    F = lambda nn,xx: np.sin(nn*np.pi*(xx+1)/2)*np.cos(nn*np.pi*(xx+1)/2);

Z = np.zeros((K,len(x)));
for n in range(1,M+1):
    pw = (1-(n/(M+1))**2)**xi; f=F(n,x)
    for k in prange(0,K):
        Z[k,:] = Z[k,:] + pw*F(n,ksi[k])*f;


    return Z


N=1000; a=-0.5; b=0.5; x=np.linspace(a,b,N); cc=x; M = 2*N+100; xi = M/40;

%timeit fun_py(M,cc,xi,x);
733 ms ± 13.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

*Julia times*

```
N=1000; a=-0.5; b=0.5; x=range(a,b,length=N); cc=x; M = 2*N+100; xi = M/40;
@benchmark fun_jul2(M,cc,xi,x)

BenchmarkTools.Trial: 
  memory estimate:  40.31 MiB
  allocs estimate:  6302
  --------------
  minimum time:     705.470 ms (0.17% GC)
  median time:      726.403 ms (0.17% GC)
  mean time:        729.032 ms (1.68% GC)
  maximum time:     765.426 ms (5.27% GC)
  --------------
  samples:          7
  evals/sample:     1
```

Comment: Does only numba parallelize? Then it is a little unfair:)

Comment: Code can be slower or faster in any language. The globals in Julia should be marked const, and the Julia code has an extra loop because both Julia and Python can do  Z[:,k] but only the Numba code is done that way. Furthermore, as Jonatan said, the k-ranged loop is run in parallel in Numba but not in Julia.

Comment: I thought that vectorization need not in Julia. Also is there a way of parallelize the julia codes as easy as in numba?

Comment: Yes, there is, using `@threads` macro to get multithreading. See comment further down.

Comment: There is one severe problem with your Numba function. Per default Numpy arrays are stored in C-order, Julia arrays are stored in Fortran order. To get a speedup of about a factor of 3 you can change the lines `Z = np.zeros((len(x),K)) `and `Z[:,k] = Z[:,k] + pw*F(n,ksi[k])*f` to `Z = np.zeros((K,(len(x)) `and `Z[k,:] = Z[k,:] + pw*F(n,ksi[k])*f`

Comment: @max911 Of course, thank you for reminding that point

Comment: Are  you using the `@threads` macro in Julia now, I can't tell since you don't include the source for `fun_jul2`.

Comment: @gggg, Yes I have updated my post.

Comment: Have you installed Intel SVML? http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/user/performance-tips.html Your timings looks a bit slow (at least for something faster than a dual core notebook processor) error_model="numpy" may also help (turning of the division by zero checking)

Comment: @max9111, No it is not installed. Also I should note that my cpu has 6 cores and 12 threads.

Comment: I got about 280ms with SVML on a 6 Core i5....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got down to 300ms on a single thread (instead of 28s on my machine) with the following code.

You are using multi-threading for Numba. In Julia you should use parallel processing (multi-threading support is experimental fo Julia). It seems that your code is doing some kind of parameter sweep - such codes are very easy to parallelize but it usually requires some adjustments to your computational process.

Here is the code:

```
function fun_jul2(M,ksi,xi,x)
  F(n,x) = sin(n*pi*(x+1))/2;
  K = length(ksi);
  L = length(x);
  Z = zeros(length(x),K);
  for n in 1:M
    F_im1= [F(n,ksi[k]) for k in 1:K]
    F_im2 = [F(n,x[l]) for l in 1:L]
    pow = (1-(n/(M+1))^2)^xi    
    for k in 1:K
       for l in 1:L    
          Z[l,k] += pow*F_im1[k]*F_im2[l];
      end
    end
  end
  Z
end
```

```
julia> fun_jul2(M,cc,xi,x) ≈ fun_jul(M,cc,xi,x)
true

julia> @time fun_jul2(M,cc,xi,x);
  0.305269 seconds (1.81 k allocations: 6.934 MiB, 1.60% gc time)
```

** EDIT: with multithreading and inbounds suggested by DNF:

```
function fun_jul3(M,ksi,xi,x)
  F(n,x) = sin(n*pi*(x+1))/2;
  K = length(ksi);
  L = length(x);
  Z = zeros(length(x),K);
  for n in 1:M
    F_im1= [F(n,ksi[k]) for k in 1:K]
    F_im2 = [F(n,x[l]) for l in 1:L]
    pow = (1-(n/(M+1))^2)^xi    
    Threads.@threads for k in 1:K
       for l in 1:L    
          @inbounds Z[l,k] += pow*F_im1[k]*F_im2[l];
      end
    end
  end
  Z
end
```

And now the running time (remember to run `set JULIA_NUM_THREADS=4` or Linux equivalent before launching Julia):

```
julia>  fun_jul2(M,cc,xi,x) ≈ fun_jul3(M,cc,xi,x)
true

julia> @time fun_jul3(M,cc,xi,x);
  0.051470 seconds (2.71 k allocations: 6.989 MiB)
```

You could also try to further experiment with parallelizing of computing of `F_im1` and `F_im2`.

Comment: What is ` ≈` ? are `fun_jul2` and `fun_jul` exactly equal or approximately equal?

Comment: ≈ means approximately equal. In floating point operations the order of computation matters so it does not make sense to test for strict equality.

Comment: @ Przemyslaw Szufel, thank you. Your suggestion greatly improved julia speed. But also I improved numba code based on your suggestion. I have updated my post.

Comment: your Numba code is multi-threaded while the Julia code is single threaded. In order to have a fair comparison run it on a single-threaded Numba code. To parallelize with Julia you will need to use multiprocessing but this is a different issue than Numba vs Julia comparison.

Comment: My main purpose is not a comparison between numba and julia. My purpose is an optimization (if possible) for julia codes or python+numba codes and I got the optimization thanks to you. I should also note that numba is so easy to parallelize, this is a plus for numba.

Comment: You can parallelize in Julia using multithreading, you do not need multiprocessing. It is equally easy as in Numba. I have tested, and get 3.5x speedup with 4 threads. Make sure that you have the right number of threads available for Julia, and then put `Threads.@threads` in front of the `k` loop. Also add an `@inbounds` in front of `Z[l, k]`.

Comment: yes, `@inbounds` is extremely useful here. I like to avoid `Threads.@threads` for larger codes due to various stability issues in favor of multiprocessing. I added an EDIT section.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to parallelize the outer loop? That should let each thread run longer, reducing overhead

Comment: @Oscar - in that case you would have to use locks - otherwise you would end up with two threads modifying the same part of the `Z`.array.

Answer (score 2):

You can do, or fail to do, loop optimization in any language that has loops. The major difference here is that the numba code is vectorized for the inner loop but the Julia code is not. To vectorize the Julia version, it is sometimes necessary to change operators to their vectorized versions with the ., so that + becomes .+ for example.

Since I cannot get Numba to install properly on my older Windows 10 machine, I ran the code versions below on free Linux versions on the Web. This means I had to use the Python interface for timeit(), not the command line.

Run in Jupyter at mybinder, probably with 1 thread since it is not specified. :

```
import timeit
timeit.timeit("""
@jit(nopython=True, parallel=True)
def fun_py(M,ksi,xi,x):

    K = len(ksi);
    F = lambda nn,xx: np.sin(nn*np.pi*(xx+1)/2)*np.cos(nn*np.pi*(xx+1)/2);

    Z = np.zeros((len(x),K));
    for n in range(1,M+1):
        for k in prange(0,K):
            Z[:,k] += (1-(n/(M+1))**2)**xi*F(n,ksi[k])*F(n,x);


    return Z


N=400; a = -0.5; b = 0.5; x = np.linspace(a,b,N); cc = x;M = 2*N + 100; xi = M/40;
fun_py(M,cc,xi,x)
""", setup ="import numpy as np; from numba import prange, jit", number=5)
```

Out[1]: 61.07768889795989

Your machine must be a lot faster than Jupyter, ForBonder.

I ran this optimized julia code version below, in Jupyter on JuliaBox, 1 thread kernel specified:

```
using BenchmarkTools

F(n, x) = sinpi.(n * (x .+ 1) / 2) .* cospi.(n * (x .+ 1) / 2)

function fun_jul2(M, ksi, xi, x)
    K = length(ksi)
    Z = zeros(length(x), K)
    for n in 1:M, k in 1:K
        Z[:, k] .+= (1 - (n / (M + 1))^2)^xi * F(n, ksi[k]) * F(n, x)
    end
    return Z
end


const N=400; const a=-0.5; const b=0.5; const x=range(a,b,length=N); 
const cc=x; const M = 2*N+100; const xi = M/40;

@btime fun_jul2(M, cc, xi, x)
```

8.076 s (1080002 allocations: 3.35 GiB)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, your julia codes are faster than mine. But still there is large speed difference between Julia and Numba. I wonder? Is there a concise or easy way of parallelizing julia codes?

Comment: Vectorizing Julia code like this does not generally lead to speedups. You only need this sort of vectorization in slow languages that use it to call a fast language under the hood. That cannot be the explanation here.

Comment: The vectorization -- in Julia and in numba both -- has the fortunate effect of avoiding doing F(n, ksi[k]) for every increment of the innermost loop, by eliminating that loop. The example Szufel gives pulls a second computation out of that loop, giving a further speedup.

Answer (score 2):

For performance, just precompute the trigonometric part. 
Indeed, `sin` is a costly operation:

```
%timeit np.sin(1.)
712 ns ± 2.22 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

%timeit 1.2*3.4
5.88 ns ± 0.016 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000000 loops each)
```

In python :

```
@jit
def fun_py2(M,ksi,xi,x):

    NN = np.arange(1,M+1)
    Fksi = np.sin(np.pi*np.outer(NN,ksi+1))/2  # sin(a)cos(a) is sin(2a)/2
    Fx = np.sin(np.pi*np.outer(NN,x+1))/2
    U = (1-(NN/(M+1))**2)**xi
    Z = np.zeros((len(x),len(ksi)))

    for n in range(len(NN)):
        for k in range(len(ksi)):
            for l in range(len(x)):
                Z[k,l] += U[n] * Fksi[n,k] * Fx[n,l];
    return Z
```

For a 30x improvement:

```
np.allclose(fun_py(M,cc,xi,x),fun_py2(M,cc,xi,x))
True

%timeit fun_py(M,cc,xi,x)
1.14 s ± 4.47 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit fun_py2(M,cc,xi,x)
29.5 ms ± 375 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

This doesn't trig any parallelism. I suppose the same will occur for Julia.